# Set dynamicaly item in ionic-menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

how I can set item in menu if I am admin.

```
this.pages = [
  { title: '*', component: *, icon: '*' },
  { title: '*', component: *, icon: '*' },
  { title: 'admin', component: *, icon: '*' }
];
```

Display on that :

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
      <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" style="margin-right: 10px; corlor: black;"></ion-icon>
      {{p.title}}
  </button>
```

And I want display `admin` item if `isAdmin` is equal `true`

Comment: you can use ng-container

Comment: Are you check it @Matthis.h

Comment: Sorry, I checked but I don't want create two menus. I want set new item inside first menu. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Ok then I removed my answer